# pxe boot environement unable to download kickstart file

Tags: fedora, nfs, pxe, unattended

Im trying to get a pxe boot working, but the farthest i can get is to the part that the pxe boot image is supposed to retrieve the kickstart file over nfs,  then the error:

```
failed to retrieve file  nfs:192.168.11.1:/distro/ks/slave-ks.cfg
```

here is my nfs exports:

```
/distro *(ro,root_squash)
```

and my tftp boot.

```
service tftp
{
    socket_type     = dgram
    protocol        = udp
    wait            = yes
    user            = root
    server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
    server_args     = -s /tftpboot
    disable         = no
    per_source      = 11
    cps         = 100 2
    flags           = IPv4
}
```

as well as  the pxe/pxelinux.cfg/C0A80B02

```
...  #  preceeding lines removed to shorten
label install
  kernel vmlinuz 
  append initrd=initrd.img network ip=dhcp lang=en US keymap=us ksdevice=p7p1 ks=nfs:192.168.11.1:/distro/ks/slave-ks.cfg loadramdisk=1 prompt_ramdisk=0 ramdisksize=16384 vga=normal selinux=0
```

i can mount the nfs share just fine and see all the files, but the pxe environment does not. Also just to ensure that the slave was getting  a network address, i pinged it  at the time it gave the error and the ipaddress was live, this is given out via dhcpd and mac address identification, so it seems like dhcp is working, tftp is working,  but for some reason nfs is not. what should i look at next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i had the wrong permissions  on the tftp directory.
something like

```
r--------
```

it seems like this will fail
so i changed it to this

```
r--r--r--
```

and it now works properly